# EmberJS 2 Dynamic Routing

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-data-url-templates

I'm trying to setup a way to define routes, their template and model dynamically. (Ember 2.16.0)

So far I have this:

```
// app/router.js
Router.map(function () {

    let routes = [
        {route: "page_one", templateName: "default.hbs"},
        {route: "page_two", templateName: "default.hbs"},
        {route: "page_three", templateName: "custom.hbs"}
    ];

    routes.forEach(function (key) {
        this.route(key.route);
    }, this);
});
```

This works, and allows me to load pages if their template file exists.

I want to take this a step further and define the template name here, for example I want them all to use "default.hbs" as well as load the model for them dynamically.

Is this something that's possible in EmberJS? If so which documentation should I be looking at to do so.

I'm aware you can specify templates in their corresponding route file "app/routes/page_one.js" but this wouldn't be dynamic.

Comment: Generally it's simpler to live with the default Ember approach to things, what are you working on accomplishing here?

Comment: I want to define routes & templates dynamically so the can be customised, like pages, from a CMS. So the route is unknown until added via a CMS. Is Ember simply not built for that?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Ember's approach to routing and templates is to use built-in templates that handle layout of data that comes from a backend.  It's perfectly possible do something like this however and end up with your CMS pages being displayed at `/page/:slug`:

// app/router.js

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('page', { path: '/:post_id' });
});
```

Doing the above would then allow you to set your `page` route to handle retrieving the appropriate data from your CMS and then display it in your `page.hbs` (with the option to wrap it with any additional HTML to make it work well in Ember).

Here's one example of an Ember add-on that does something like that. https://github.com/oskarrough/ember-wordpress  It also has a working test app that is designed to work against a Wordpress backend that you can study here: https://github.com/oskarrough/ember-wordpress/tree/master/tests/dummy

There are other approaches you could take as well, but this is probably the simplest one.  Does that help?